# Bootstrap 4 select form field isn't working with django

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-4, html-select

I am new to django and using bootstrap4 form with django. When I use input field *text* and *date*   it works fine and save data into django admin but if I add *Select* for categories, it doesn't work and returns following error:
**ValueError at /
The view app_budgetlist.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

I worked for 2 straight days and couldn't figure out what's wrong! Can you help please?
[N.B. Updated the code as @Caleb Goodman told still no luck]
Here is my code:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MonthlyBudget(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    budget_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import MonthlyBudget

class MonthlyBudgetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MonthlyBudget
        fields = ['category', 'budget_amount']
```

*view.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Category, MonthlyBudget
from .forms import MonthlyBudgetForm 

def home(request):
    project = MonthlyBudget.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form =  MonthlyBudgetForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'project':project, 'categories':categories})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'project':project, 'categories':categories})
```

*home.html*

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="budget_amount" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="budget-amount" placeholder="Amount">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="category">Select Category</label>

                            <select id="category" class="taskCategory" name="category">
                                <option class="disabled" value="">Choose a category</option>
                                {% for category in categories %}
                                    <option class="" value="{{ category.name }}" name="{{ category.name }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add Project</button>
                </form>
```

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MonthlyBudget, Category

admin.site.register(MonthlyBudget)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return a response after you save the form:

```
def home(request):
    project = MonthlyBudget.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form =  MonthlyBudgetForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'project':project, 'categories':categories})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'project':project, 'categories':categories})
```

Comment: pasted it but doesn't work. I think the problem is on my forms.py. Category Model isn't defined there? Could it cause the issue?